# Copy files from one folder to another with random prefix

Tags: powershell, csv, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy files from one folder to another.
I have some sort of random prefix i my files. but i have the last part of the filename in a csv file.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\newpart\xxx\$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))_test" -Force
Import-Csv '\\csvpath\xxx\file.csv' | 
  ForEach {Copy-Item -path \\oldpath\xxx\* -filter $($_.Fil) "\\newpath\xxx\$((Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))_text" }
```

**my files looks the this:**

```
{001588D8-5FF0-409C-9BF7-A3AE6D0B26CF} - AppImage20160520115646078.jpg
```

CSV file only have this part of the filename:

```
AppImage20160520115646078.jpg
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What would be the expected result?

Comment: Nothing happens, i think the problem is my `-filter`.

Comment: if i write `-path \\oldpath\xxx\$($_.Fil)` the file complains because i have a random prefix before the file name in the .csv document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*` wildcard in `-filter "*$($_.Fil)"`.

On the other side, [`Copy-Item` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.management/Copy-Item) says that its `-Path` parameter **does not accept wildcard characters**.

```
$newTarget = "\\newpart\xxx\$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))_test"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$newTarget" -Force
Import-Csv '\\csvpath\xxx\file.csv' | 
    ForEach { 
        Get-ChildItem "\\oldpath\xxx\*$($_.Fil)" -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            ForEach { Copy-Item -path $PSItem.FullName -Destination "$newTarget" }
    }
```

or (maybe better)

```
$newTarget = "\\newpart\xxx\$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))_test"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$newTarget" -Force
Import-Csv '\\csvpath\xxx\file.csv' | 
    ForEach { 
        Get-ChildItem "\\oldpath\xxx\*$($_.Fil)" -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Copy-Item -Destination "$newTarget"
    }
```

Comment: i get the same result, blank folders

Comment: @DanielChristensen answer updated.

Comment: The folder is still empty. what if i use a `where-object -like` ?

Comment: it works if i insert the name manuel `Where-Object   {$_.Name -like "xxxxx"}`

Comment: I got it now i just need to make `$($_.Fil)` to a string with `[string]`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this in a script file e.g. Copy-FilesFromCsv.ps1:

```
#mkdir files
#touch "files\{001588D8-5FF0-409C-9BF7-A3AE6D0B26CF} - AppImage20160520115646078.jpg"

$csvPath = "$PSScriptRoot\" # "\\csvpath\xxx\"
$sourceFolder = "$PSScriptRoot\files\"
$newFolder = "$PSScriptRoot\files\$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))_test"
New-Item -WhatIf -ItemType Directory $newFolder -Force


ForEach ($file in $(Import-Csv "${csvPath}file.csv"))
{
    Copy-Item -WhatIf -Path "$sourceFolder*$($file.Fil)" -Destination $newFolder
}
```

Comment: i get a blank new folder :/

Comment: Could you upload a log of the shell when you run it? and if you have made any changes to my script?